# Dropdown menu sliding up when losing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar menu on my website, when in a mobile phone it turns into a "Navigation" panel that slides down when pressed. My problem is that I want the "Navigation" menu to only  `slide up` when I click this Navigation button, and only if.

What is occuring is that the navigation menu slides up when I focus on the search input, that is inside this Navigation Menu, and I can't type anything. (**The error only occur on mobile phones, works fine on a resized desktop browser**).

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('click', ".sidebar-dropdown a", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if(!$(this).hasClass("dropy")) 
  {
    // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
    $(".sidebar .sidebar-inner").slideUp(350);
    $(".sidebar-dropdown a").removeClass("dropy");

    // open our new menu and add the dropy class
    $(".sidebar .sidebar-inner").slideDown(350);
    $(this).addClass("dropy");
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).removeClass("dropy");
    $(".sidebar .sidebar-inner").slideUp(350);
  }
});

});
```

Here is an example of the bug (I use this Bootstrap theme on my website): http://responsivewebinc.com/premium/metroking/

Comment: Why are you hooking up the event to "document" instead of ".sidebar-dropdown a" directly?

Comment: I just use it as a pattern because I use alot of dynamically created objects, for this specific object there is no reason. Why? There is a downside?

Comment: Yes - you need to run your code on every event, even if there is no handler hooked up to the clicked element.